# Remove Item from Json File With multiple condition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I Have a **files.json** with content:

```
[
  {
    "fileName": "product1.zip",
    "fileSize": "5.08 KB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives1\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product1.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.39 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product2.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.38 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives1\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product2.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.37 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
  }
]
```

How to remove item with multiple condition in **PHP** and return other items
if: fileName = "product1.zip" & restoreDir = "Files/Archives1/" and save again into **files.json**

Expected Result in **files.json**:

```
[
      {
        "fileName": "product1.zip",
        "fileSize": "1.39 MB",
        "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "product2.zip",
        "fileSize": "1.38 MB",
        "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives1\/"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "product2.zip",
        "fileSize": "1.37 MB",
        "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
      }
    ]
```

Thanks,

Comment: try fetching and rewriting the .json file, with the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, that removes all items that match the criteria. However, if you're sure there's only ever going to be **one** item that match the criteria, this is inefficient, because it evaluates **all** items.

If you want this "simpler" version, you should just loop though `$decoded` (with a `for( ; ; )` or `foreach()`) and as soon as the criteria are met, remove the item from the array and `break` out of the loop.

```php
$json = <<<'JSON'
[
  {
    "fileName": "product1.zip",
    "fileSize": "5.08 KB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives1\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product1.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.39 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product2.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.38 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives1\/"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "product2.zip",
    "fileSize": "1.37 MB",
    "restoreDir": "Files\/Archives2\/"
  }
]
JSON;

$criteria = [
  'fileName'   => 'product1.zip',
  'restoreDir' => 'Files/Archives1/'
];

$decoded = json_decode( $json, true );
$filtered = array_filter( $decoded, function( $item ) use ( $criteria ) {
  return array_intersect_assoc( $criteria, $item ) !== $criteria;
} );
$result = json_encode( $filtered, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

var_dump( $result );
```

[<sup>view parsed online @ eval.in</sup>](https://eval.in/1040291)